# Dropwizard jackson yaml configuration mapping

Tags: java, maven, jackson, dropwizard

Using dropwizard version 0.9.2 and the configuration yml looks somewhat like this

```
server:
    applicationConnectors:
      - type: http
        port: 8090
    adminConnectors:
      - type: http
        port: 8091
    requestLog:
      timeZone: UTC
      appenders:
        - type: file
          currentLogFilename: file
          threshold: ALL
          archive: true
          archivedLogFilenamePattern: some-pattern
          archivedFileCount: 5
          maxFileSize: 10MB
```

While executing getting the following error

```
* Unrecognized field at: server.requestLog
    Did you mean?:
      - adminConnectors
      - adminContextPath
      - adminMaxThreads
```

On search seems like this error is known in Jackson and fixed in [2.7.3](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/1449#issuecomment-180763537). So, upgraded dropwizard to latest 1.0.2 but still the problem persists.

Also, tried excluding jackson explicitly and include the latest 2.8.3 didn't help either. Any inputs on solving this issue ?

Tried pom

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dropwizard-jackson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Since you are mixing dependencies, is there a change that you have older versions of the DefaultServerFactory on your classpath?

Comment: Have deleted full .m2 local repository to be safe. No overlapping classpath

Comment: maybe they are pulled in through other dependencies. You can do a mvn dependency:tree. this works fine for me with DW 1.0.0 out of the box. Note that there is a breaking change between 0.9.2 and 1.0.0 as well (timezone is gone)

Comment: Thank you it helped a bit. Since timezone is gone, how does server request log works. Can you direct me to some resource. I couldn't get access log working.

Comment: This depends on the version you are using as the configuration has changed. Since you are using 2 different versions in your question, this is not clear to me, but the request log examples are on their official documentation page: http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.2/docs/manual/configuration.html#request-log

Comment: Thank you the bug has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Logging is not part of server configurations.

```
server:
    applicationConnectors:
     - type: http
       port: 8090
    adminConnectors:
     - type: http
       port: 8091
logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
     requestLog: INFO
  appenders:
```

Use "logging" instead